# What are the Common Practices for Java Development on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat, jetty

I'm trying to migrate from Windows to Linux as a Java development platform, and while the transition has generally been pretty painless, there are a few points of uncertainty that I'd like some feedback on. I'm running openSUSE 11.4, but I'm open to hear what works on other distros.

1. **Where do you install your JDK from?** This one is surprisingly not as cut and dry as most people make it out to be. OpenJDk 6 is available in the openSUSE repositories, and was very easy to install. However it's currently update 21, and right now the Oracle release is at update 24. I'm used to a little alert in Windows notifying me that my Java needs updating but that doesn't appear to be the norm in Linux. Do Java developers forgo the JDK in their package manager and install the binary directly? Or is there another way?
2. **Where do you install Eclipse?** There seems to be a general agreement online that Eclipse is best installed by simply downloading the binary and extracting it somewhere, but where's the usual place I would extract a program like Eclipse or Ant? I've seen votes for /usr/local and /opt online, but no definitive answer.
3. **Where do you put your Jetty/Tomcat?** Similar to the eclipse question, where do most Linux Java developers put their Jetty/Tomcat/other container.
4. **What are some of the differences between the way you setup development versus production** At the very least it seems I don't want to run my servlet container as root, that makes sense to me. But what other practices should I watch out for? Is there anything else that could make my development environment easier, but perhaps less secure?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793071/how-to-start-using-and-developing-on-ubuntu-linux) was similar but ultimately too high level and didn't get into details of how actual developers are setting up their environment. If there's other resources you feel answer these questions, please share them here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have to stick with suse? In Debian / Ubuntu / LinuxMint all this downloading / installation stuff would be possible in one simple commandline.

Comment: I'm not heavily invested in openSUSE, but it was my introduction to Linux via Mono. I think my prefernece would be to stick with a distro that uses rpm, but I'd love to learn more about Debian. I didn't want to ask 'which linux distro should I use?' because those seem to devolve into a flame war by people who have never actually done any development. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161697/best-linux-distro-for-web-development seems to suffer from that.

Comment: Also on Fedora install like this `yum install java-devel`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q>** Where do you install your JDK from?
**A>** I never bother with other JDKs coming from outside Sun/Oracle mainly because our product is only certified to work with Sun/Oracle JRE. On my desktop, I run Kubuntu, but I never use `apt-get` for this but always download them manually. Reasons:

- distro maintainers rarely rush to upgrade packages, as their primary concern is to make dependant apps (such as OpenOffice) work. If JDK changes from 1.6.0_20 to 1.6.0_21, they simply don't care. I might do because a newer patch might have an important bugfix or I simply want to try if my app still passes all the unit tests.
- it might be a nightmare to retain old JDK versions. We still support older versions of our product and if I upgrade to a newer Kubuntu, I don't have guarantees that some ancient JDK will still be available as a package.
- I am not sure some distros even support multiple existence of JDKs on the same machine.

My preference is to keep all JDKs/JREs in `/opt` and make a symlink to the newest one or the one I need most. I simply don't see why installing JDK manually is a problem.

I also set the `PATH` to the newest JDK/JRE.

Same thing (and similar arguments) apply to `Ant` and `Maven`.

**Q>** Where do you install Eclipse? 
**A>** I use IntelliJ but the same applies. I store IDE in my home folder. This allows me to have different versions of it, update them without needing `sudo`, etc. I could as well install it in `/opt` but I guess I got this habit when I was downloading and testing newest IntelliJ IDEA EAP every week so I can quickly delete the older versions and do not pollute `/opt`. Finally, other programs might require Ant/Maven/JDK but it's only me who uses IntelliJ hence the different approach.

**Q>** Where do you put your Jetty/Tomcat?
**A>** I have a separate folder `tomcats` under `/home` where I have ~10 different Tomcat instances. Each of Tomcats is used for a different version of my app (we bundle Tomcat with our app). This is necessary because one deployment of our app can have different Tomcat settings (or even version) than another.

**Q>** What are some of the differences between the way you setup development versus production
**A>** It very much depends on your app. For example, we need some partitions to have lower access latencies but having less space (e.g. gigabytes for Lucene indexes) VS others which can have higher latencies but require more space (e.g. terabytes for content repositories). We, however, design our app so that all these different aspects can reside on different partitions which are configurable. Some partitions need to have special limitations (e.g. file upload) so this doesn't overflow other partitions. There is no simple one-for-all answer to this question, but obviously most of these concerns don't matter that much for a development environment.

Answer (score 3):

> Where do you install your JDK from?

I use Arch Linux myself, and we have the oracle jdk/jre in the repository itself. Hence, use your distro-repository if it has the oracle jdk/jre else get it from oracle itself.

> Where do you install Eclipse?

Again, the same answer as above applies to this as well. If however, there is any issue with the distro provided version, I always put my custom installs in /opt/ - /opt/java , /opt/eclipse, /opt/netbeans - etc. I dont install stuff in my home folder (except in circumstances where I don't have permission anywhere else - rare), since that would mean that other users would need access to my home folder to run the stuff. I don't want production (or development for that matter) stuff having direct access to my home.

> Where do you put your Jetty/Tomcat?

The same answer as above applies here as well. Only in circumstances, where I have installed more than one version, I create an /opt/experimental/ and install there so that I know which one my production is running and which one I can remove when no longer required.

> What are some of the differences
>   between the way you setup development
>   versus production?

If possible, I always setup different machines for production and development work. Different computers, but exactly identical setup. The only systems that can push code to the production system are those in the development group. Where this segregation is not possible, I prefer to have different install for the servers, so that while I am tweaking the development configuration, my main servers don't crash or something. Also development setup will generally include a clean_up script that makes it ready for production (dropping unnecessary priviledges for db accounts, cleaning up, etc.

Have whatever, setup you will, just make sure you have different database setup for development and production purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The Sun version of Java for openSUSE is on the nonOSS disk ([go here and scroll down for an ISO](http://software.opensuse.org/114/en)), which is an additional disk image, not part of the main install disk ISO (or you can pull the RPMs from [here](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.4/repo/non-oss/suse/)).

As far as eclipse is concerned, if I'm installing at the system level, I tend to drop it in /opt. You might want to read [this article](http://blog.exis.com/colin/archives/2004/12/23/managing-plugins-in-eclipse/) on how best to handle plugins.

(Don't let them steer you off openSUSE, it is the best distro for KDE IMO.)

Comment: YaST is probably worth a mention for general updating.

Answer (score 1):

Working with linux is a lot less hand holding then the windows environment that you're use too.  If I were you I would switch distros to either RedHat or Ubuntu, I use to use SUSE and never looked back since I switched.

You can put your JDK/Eclipse/Tomcat binaries in a couple of different places.  If you are the only one going to be using them I suggest you put them in your home directory somewhere.  For your Eclipse/Tomcat stuff you can but them in a local bin and then add that local bin to your PATH in your .bashrc.  You can also set the location of your JDK to a JAVA_HOME env variable in your bash.  If you need any more specific help with setup let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1) We have had several problems with OpenJDK (bugs, etc) so we always use the sun jdk.

2/3) A good rule to live by when living in Linux, is always install your custom software under your home folder. Linux needs to be reinstalled from time to time, but everything in your home folder is in a separate disk-partition, so it lives on. I always installs/unzips custom software such as eclipse to /home/myuser/opt, so my eclipse lives at ~/opt/eclipse. I also symlinks the eclipse-binary to my /home/myuser/bin folder for easy access. When I upgrade or change any software, I just rewire the symlink.

4) Production and development environments should be as close as possible to identical. This elimenate loads of bugs caused by different configurations etc.

Comment: 1) Thanks, I'll look into moving to the sun/oracle JDK. I was under the impression that openJDK WAS Sun's JDK for Linux. Do you install the binary directly or rely on a package manager? 2) Makes sense, I was hesitant to follow this path because it felt like installing Office to My Documents in a Windows mindset.

Comment: I was using sunkjdk but can't find the oracle jdk with ubuntu/kubuntu10?   At least through the package manager.

Comment: Uhm, Linux does NOT have to be reinstalled from time to time. And in what way your disc is partitioned is up to you.

Comment: "Linux needs to be reinstalled from time to time" - May I ask on what grounds did you base that statement? Now, if one plays around without much care, then its an entirely different thing.

IMO its better to install stuffs in /usr/local/ or /opt since if you reinstall for whatever reason, chances are high that because of underlaying dependencies, you'd have to reinstall/recompile your custom software too.

Answer (score 0):

I create a /usr/local/java directory and unpack the JDK(s), Eclipse, Maven, Ant, Groovy and Grails in there, then create symlinks to /usr/local/bin.